# HTML Form: Make div as submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I've created a webpage including a folder structure hierarchy using –`html/php/js/mysql`.

Therefore, I've created a design. It's simply a parent div with the `class` of `folders` and inside all folders are listed with an `<h2>` as the name. Through `PHP` I've set the folder ID as a custom attribute on each folder div:

```
<div class="folders">
   <div data-id="12452">
      <h2>Folder 1</h2>
   </div
   <div data-id="12453">
      <h2>Folder 2</h2>
   </div
   <div data-id="12454">
      <h2>Folder 3</h2>
   </div
</div>
```

Now, I would like to do that when someone clicks on `folder one`, a get parameter should be set in the `url`.

So basically the URL:

`mywebpage.com/index.php ->'clicks folder' -> mywebpage.com/index.php?folder=12452`

I have a couple of ideas how I could achieve that, like creating a hidden form that will be submitted with javascript when clicking a folder div, but I'm not quite sure which way is the best and cleanest.

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: One thing to consider is if somebody edits the hidden form and submits it to see if they break anything, or worse.

Comment: Well that could definitely be dealt with some smart php coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, adding a click handler on the parent, and track which child were clicked on, and get its `data-id`

From there you can e.g. assign that *url* to a `form` and post it using the `form`'s `submit()` method

Stack snippet

```js
document.querySelector('.folders').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.closest('div').dataset.id) {
     var url = "mywebpage.com/index.php?folder=" + e.target.closest('div').dataset.id;
     
     console.log(url);
     
     // e.g.
     /*
       var form = document.querySelector('form');
       form.action = url;
       form.hidden_field.value = "some value";
       form.submit();     
     */
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="folders">
   <div data-id="12452">
      <h2>Folder 1</h2>
   </div>
   <div data-id="12453">
      <h2>Folder 2</h2>
   </div>
   <div data-id="12454">
      <h2>Folder 3</h2>
   </div>
</div>
<form id="the_form">
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden_field" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery you could attach a simple click like the following snippet shows.

**NOTE:** If you want from the `h2` to looks like a clickable element you count change the cursor to `pointer` in your CSS rules like :

```
.folders h2 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```js
$('.folders h2').click(function() {
  var folder_id = $(this).parent().data('id');

  //This line was added just for log purpose
  console.log('?folder=' + folder_id);

  //Uncomment the following line that will redirect you with folder "id" as parameter
  //location.href = '?folder=' + folder_id;
})
```

```css
.folders h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="folders">
  <div data-id="12452">
    <h2>Folder 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div data-id="12453">
    <h2>Folder 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div data-id="12454">
    <h2>Folder 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but that wont add to the url, it will set it, right?